# How to create a table with cascaded rows

Tags: tables

[image]

I am unable to get the layout as shown also i am unable to get the ions in column 1. Na+ doesn't come the way it is required. Kindly help

This is what i wrote

```
\begin {tabular}{||c||c||c||}
\hline
\ Ion & SBF & HBP \\
\hline
 Na^{+} & 142 & 142 \\
 \hline
 K^{+} & 5 & 5 \\
 \hline
 Mg^{2+} &  1.5 & 1.5 \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) We kindly suggest you to show a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) on what you have worked so far, so we can help you further with your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixes what you've written:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline

 \multirow{2}{*}{Ion} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Concentration (mmol/dm$^3$)}\\
 \cline{2-3}
 & Simulated Body Fluid (SBF) & Human Blood Plasma (HBP) \\

\hline

Na$^{+}$ & 142 & 142 \\

\hline

K$^{+}$ & 5 & 5 \\

\hline

Mg$^{2+}$ & 1.5 & 1.5 \\

\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

You can add the remaining rows.

Comment: Maybe you could add the `mhchem` package to support easier input of chemical formulas using e.g `\ce{K+}`.